# Joining threads while exception is thrown

Tags: multithreading, c++11, ubuntu, exception, arm

I am using the C++ 11 std::thread library. Is it valid to join a thread in a destructor while an exception is thrown? The code I have is:

```
#include <thread>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <exception>
#include <unistd.h>

class the_thread {
private:
    std::thread t;
    bool abort;
public:
    the_thread();
    ~the_thread();

    void run();
};

the_thread::the_thread()
{
    abort = false;
    t = std::thread(&the_thread::run, this);
#if 0
    printf("before detach ...\n");
    t.detach();
    printf("after detach ...\n");
#endif
}

the_thread::~the_thread()
{
    abort = true;

printf("destruct thread container\n");
    if (t.joinable()) {
printf("into join\n");
        t.join();
printf("out of join\n");
    }
}

void the_thread::run()
{
    int i;

    i=0;
    while (!abort) {
        printf("hallo %d\n", i);
        i++;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(3000));
    }
}

int run_thread_and_throw_exception(void)
{
    the_thread t;

    sleep(5);
    throw std::runtime_error("some expected exception");
}


int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    try {
        run_thread_and_throw_exception();
    } catch (const std::runtime_error &e) {
        printf("exception %s caught\n", e.what());
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When compiling and running with

```
gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) 5.4.0 20160609
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

on my Ubuntu 16.04 development machine, this code behaves as expected:

```
bash$ ./thread_test 
hallo 0
hallo 1
destruct thread container
into join
out of join
exception some expected exception caught
bash$
```

However when compiling with

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ -Wall -g -O2 -std=c++11   -c -o main.o main.cpp
arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ -Wall -g -O2 -std=c++11 main.o -o thread_test -lpthread -static
```

(we need the -static because there is no C++ 11 library on the target) and running it on the target, strange things happen:

```
bash-on-target# ./thread_test
hallo 0
hallo 1
destruct thread container
into join
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
  what():  Unknown error 1082172112
Aborted
```

So it seems that the join in the destructor fails for some reason. Furthermore when trying to detach the thread, the detach fails rightaway:

```
bash-on-target# ./thread_test
before detach ...
terminate called without an active exception
hallo 0
hallo 0
Aborted
```

So to repeat my question: is joining threads (and possibly sleeping) while an exception is thrown valid in C++11? Is it possible that there is a bug in the C++ 11 library for ARM that comes with Ubuntu 16.04?

The ARM toolchain is:

```
bash$ arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ --version
arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9) 5.4.0 20160609
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Thanks and best wishes, Johannes

Comment: Probably unrelated but you have a race condition here, which is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Yes, it is possible (albeit unlikely) that there is a bug in the standard library. Also, check the documentation: If I remember right, some targets used to take a `-lpthread` while others wanted a `-pthread`. Lastly, run that code in a debugger to find out where the exception is thrown.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardtone Good catch. One *does* need `-pthread` when *compiling*, regardless of platform.